# PHP: How to access Associative Array and solve "Array to String conversion notice"?

Tags: php, arrays, json, associative-array

EDIT: I found my mistake thanks to the comments about decoding the JSON data.

I am a total rookie in PHP and couldn't find a suitable method to access Associative array.

I have this JSON data:

```
[{"Id":"1"},{"Id":"2"},{"Id":"3"},{"Id":"4"},{"Id":"5"},{"Id":"6"},{"Id":"7"},{"Id":"8"}]
```

I need to fire another MySQLi query in my PHP code which requires 1,2,3... from above data.

Implementing various solutions on this site gives me Array to String Conversion error.
Please Help.

Comment: you need to json data to associative array or ??

Comment: Read about `json_decode()`.

Comment: what you have there is a json string, so try to convert it into a regular array first with json_decode($string, TRUE);

Comment: @Ramki: What are you trying to say?

Comment: @SpongePablo: Yes I'll do that! Thanks!

Comment: @ Kaushal Shah i have answered your question please check it

Comment: the piece of code that parses your array would help as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `array_column` amd `implode` as

```
$json = '[{"Id":"1"},{"Id":"2"},{"Id":"3"},{"Id":"4"},{"Id":"5"},{"Id":"6"},{"Id":"7"},{"Id":"8"}]';
$data = implode(',',array_column(json_decode($json,true),'Id'));
echo $data;//1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

**Explanation:**

1. `json_decode($json,true)` will convert your `json` string into an array
2. `array_column(json_decode($json,true),'Id')` will returns the values from a single column of the array, identified by the **column_key** i.e `Id` over here
3. `implode` will `Join` array elements with a **glue string** i.e `,`.

Answer (score 0):

convert json data to associative array:

```
<?php
$json = '[{"Id":"1"},{"Id":"2"},{"Id":"3"},{"Id":"4"},{"Id":"5"},{"Id":"6"},{"Id":"7"},{"Id":"8"}]';
$data = json_decode($json,true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "<pre>";
?>
```